# C Assigning values to a struct works with debug flags, but not with release flags

Tags: c

I'm working with C and OpenGL. I have a sprite struct, and a function to create a new sprite and set its' values. The function works correctly with debug linker flags, but when I compile it with release optimizations, some sprite values are set to 0. What am I doing wrong?

**Minimal code example (EDITED):**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} position;

typedef struct {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;
} colorrgba8;

typedef struct {
    float u;
    float v;
} UV;

typedef struct {
    position pos;
    colorrgba8 color;
    UV uv;
} vertex;

typedef struct {
    float x, y, z;
    float width, height;

    vertex tr;
    vertex tl;
    vertex bl;
    vertex br;
} sprite;

vertex set_position(float x, float y, float z) {
    vertex ver;
    ver.pos.x = x;
    ver.pos.y = y;
    ver.pos.z = z;
    return ver;
}

vertex set_color(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
    vertex ver;
    ver.color.r = r;
    ver.color.g = g;
    ver.color.b = b;
    ver.color.a = a;
    return ver;
}

vertex set_uv(float u, float v) {
    vertex ver;
    ver.uv.u = u;
    ver.uv.v = v;
    return ver;
}

sprite*  sprite_new(float x, float y, float z, float width, float height) {
    sprite* s = malloc(sizeof(sprite));

    s->x = x;
    s->y = y;
    s->z = z;
    s->width = width;
    s->height = height;

    s->tr = set_position(x + width, y + height, z);
    s->tr = set_uv(1.0f, 1.0f);
    s->tr = set_color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    s->tl = set_position(x, y + height, z);
    s->tl = set_uv(0.0f, 1.0f);
    s->tl = set_color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    s->bl = set_position(x, y, z);
    s->bl = set_uv(0.0f, 0.0f);
    s->bl = set_color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    s->br = set_position(x + width, y, z);
    s->br = set_uv(1.0f, 0.0f);
    s->br = set_color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


    return s;
}
```

**I call the function like this:**

```
sprite* s = sprite_new(100.0f, 100.0f, -100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);

printf("Top right vertex pos.x: %f | Bottom left vertex pos.z: %f\n", s->tr.pos.x, s->bl.pos.z);
```

Output with release flags: -O2

Top right vertex pos.x: 0.000000 | Bottom left vertex pos.z: 0.000000

Output with debug flags: -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -std=c99 -pedantic-errors

Top right vertex pos.x: 200.000000 | Bottom left vertex pos.z: -100.000000

Comment: If `malloc` returns an error, you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @olaf if `malloc` returns an "error", it returns NULL, which is going to cause his application to crash when he dereferences it... unless he's on a system without memory protection (which seems pretty unlikely, particularly given that he's using opengl).

Comment: `vertex tr;` should generate an error, because `vertex` is not defined. Similar for `position`. As it seems to compile and run, youi do not show the actual code. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mah: 1) `NULL` is a macro, it cannot be returned by a function. `malloc` returns a _null pointer_ on error. 2) Please point me at where the C standard requires an application to crash. Dereferencing a _null pointer_ is UB. (And OpenGL might very well be on embedded systems without cushions.

Comment: @olaf 1) Yes, `NULL` is a macro... don't be obtuse about what the macro is defined as though... it's defined as a pointer to address 0 . 2) there isn't any requirement for an application that tries to dereference address 0 to crash... it's just what happens on every non-obscure system you can think of that uses memory protection (and I don't think you can name a system that supports opengl and doesn't enforce memory protection). Even though the standard is undefined, it's very unproductive to suggest otherwise (with very limited exceptions typically involving embedded systems).

Comment: after fixing the order of definition, the code runs fine with gcc 4.6.3. seems like a compiler bug.

Comment: @mah: A _null pointer_ is not the same as a pointer to address 0. The C standard does neither require a _null pointer_ to have a single representation, nor this to have all bits zero. For the rest: Please get some  broader experience with e.g. embedded systems before stating that. You are wrong. Finally: it is useless to deviate from the standard without actual need. I did not even state this was the fault - that's not what comments are for. (Neither they are to ddiscuss the C standard - you have the last word)

Comment: @user3528438: Unlikely, gcc normally does warn. I suspect these are not the droids we are looking for (i.e.: not the actual code;-).

Comment: @mah: I did not start a dogfight about relying on UB. My original comment just implied using good practice is to check the result of `malloc` et al. and correctly terminate instead of just hoping someone else cares cleans up your mess.

Comment: @olaf I agree with your recommendation for doing proper error checking etc., but I do not see how your initial comment implied that at all. Rather, the lack of anything beyond what amounts to "this is bad" implies that fixing it would resolve the issue, which clearly is not what you intend.

Comment: @mah: As the clairvoyant you apparently are, how about better putting the effort into answering the question rather than trying to read my intention?

Comment: @olaf if I knew the answer to his problem I would. As to reading your intention -- I'm not, I'm reading your comment and informing you of what it implies to an objective reader. By definition, you cannot be objective about your own post. Obviously you know what you meant but if others do not, you have failed to communicate well. If you accept that you failed to express yourself adequately, you can probably improve it. If instead you just respond defensively, you're doomed to learn nothing. With over 20 years as a professional, surely you possess an ability to accept constructive criticism.

Comment: @mah: Oh, I very well do. But it is all a matter of how it is communicated. Responding with wrong claims is one of the worst approaches.

Comment: @olaf It's unfortunate that you're unable to grasp what I've said so I'll give up. Have a nice day, sir.

Comment: I edited the code to a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly initializing vertexes in various vertex functions.

In the first function that is called, `set_position`, you define a local vertex, and fully set member `pos` and its members with some values:

```
vertex set_position(float x, float y, float z) {
    vertex ver;
    ver.pos.x = x;
    ver.pos.y = y;
    ver.pos.z = z;
    return ver;
}
```

however you forget to set the other members, and then the struct is returned with some uninitialized members. I.e. the struct from the function which is partially uninitialized is assigned to `s->tr`. Other members' values are indeterminate. Reading those members causes undefined behavior. All three functions suffer from this problem.

If you are not going to set the other elements, and the code can handle its default values then initialized the struct *properly* with default initializers for all its members:

```
vertex ver = { 0 } ;
```

The second problem is that the next two function overwrite the member `tr` of struct sprite. For every call, `tr` is overwritten. After the last call of function `set_color`, only members of tr.color are set and the rest are set to indeterminate values.

```
s->tr = set_position(x + width, y + height, z);
s->tr = set_uv(1.0f, 1.0f);
s->tr = set_color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

The rest of the code replicates these same mistakes.